# efficient coding in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a large sample values in "sample.txt". These values in each row  are taken for each xi and run in the model-linux.
Currently the code is not written to run in parallel. 
Is there any way to reduce the run time by either making it run parallel or by using an alternative to the for loop. 
My code is

```
 setwd('/phd/90-91')

    ptm <- proc.time()
    xxx = read.table('~/90-91/sample.txt');

    alls = dim(xxx);
    objs=vector()

    nse= numeric()
    rmse=numeric()
    revf=numeric()

    for (xi in 1:alls[1])
    {
      print(xi)
      system(sprintf("./shtran_cng_nlst.sh  %s", xi) )
      objs [xi] = xi
      system("./model-linux -f rundata.txt")
      sim <- read.table("/phd//90-91 /outputdischarge_sim_regulartimestep.txt",fill=TRUE,header = FALSE,skip=1)
      obs <- read.table("/phd/90-91/observeddisch.txt",fill=TRUE,header = FALSE,skip=1)
      nsesh[xi]= 1-{sum((obs[366:730,1]-sim[366:730,1])^2)/sum((obs[366:730,1]-mean(obs[366:730,1]))^2)}
      rmsesh[xi]=sqrt((1/365)*sum((obs[366:730,1]-sim[366:730,1])^2))
      revfsh[xi]=1-((sum(sim[366:730,1]))/(sum(obs[366:730,1])))

     save(nsesh,file="/phd/90-91/nse_she")
    save(rmsesh,file="/phd/90-91/rmse_she")
    save(revfsh,file="/phd/90-91/revf_she")

   write(nsesh,"/phd/90-91/nse_she.txt", ncolumns = 1, append = FALSE, sep="\t")
  write(rmsesh,"/phd/90-91/rmse_she.txt", ncolumns = 1, append = FALSE, sep="\t")
  write(revfsh,"/phd/90-91/revf_she.txt", ncolumns = 1, append = FALSE, sep="\t")

    }


    proc.time() - ptm
```

Comment: What does your shell scripts do?  If you can parallelize depends on what you want to do.

Comment: The shell script "./shtran_cng_nlst.sh" mainly denotes the location of the samples to be edited in the files to be fed as an input to model-linux. sample.txt has 620 rows with 30columns. ./shtran_cng_nlst.sh edits the input files (for model-linux)with the values in sample.txt for each of the 620 rows/runs.

Comment: Can you provide reproducible example for your problem?  Without knowing your tasks, it is almost impossible for people to tell what you can do better.